# How to make scatter plot with connections and colors for paired data in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a pair data first column shows some values for individuals with disease and column 2 contains values for individuals without disease. I would like to make an scatter plot showing in the x-axis those with disease and in the y-axis those without disease. I want to show disease and non-diseases with two colors and also connect the pairs by line. Each row shows the pairs. For example pair 1 with disease value = 27 and pair 2 without disease value= 29 and so on. I have tried below, but I am not sure how to continue the rest. Any guidance is appreciated.

```
d <- structure(list(id_case = c(27, 17, 35, 18, 27, 40, 20, 25, 30, 20, 35, 26, 30, 31, 15, 11, 41), 
                    id_control = c(29, 26, 39, 22, 24, 41, 29, 24, 25, 21, 29, 24, 26, 29, 15, 11, 35)), 
                    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -17L))

ggplot(d, aes(id_case, id_control))+geom_point()+
  xlab("with disease")+ylab("without disease")
```

Comment: It is not clear, what this means?: *I would like to make an scatter plot showing in the x-axis those with disease and in the y-axis those without disease. I want to show disease and non-diseases with two colors and also connect the pairs by line.*

Comment: If you only have two variables, then a scatter plot will show a single point for each row, so for example the first point would be at x = 27, y = 29. This is a single point, so you can't color it by different groups. Perhaps a sketch of what you are trying to achieve will help?

Comment: I think your question makes no sense. Each point will have information from both the "disease" (x-axis) and "no disease" (y-axis) groups, so there's no way to color the points by the group. That is like coloring a point by whether it has a position on the x-axis, or a position on the y-axis, but by definition, each point has both.